# Hive order by returning null and wrong result

Tags: hive, cloudera

I have created a simple table in hive and loaded around 37k records with 50 columns.

I am trying to run one query with ORDER BY. It's returning wrong details.

```
SELECT col1, col2 from table1 ORDER BY col3 limit 10;
```

I also created a new table and inserted data in that using below query. It also inserted wrong data.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tab2
   select * from tab1 ORDER BY col3;
```

But when I am running same query to limit no. of output rows to less then it's giving correct result.

```
SELECT col1, col2 from tab1 WHERE col1 = 'xyz' ORDER BY col3 limit 20;
```

I am using Cloudera virtualbox. Where can I check what is the issue and why it's giving wrong result ? I tried to see job log, but not able to find what is the issue. I am new to Hive so any guidance will be helpful.

Is it some setup issue or some limitation of CDH?

Comment: How table2 is related with this issue? You are inserting into it without limit. And select from table2 without order by clause will normally return not ordered dataset

Comment: I am inserting data in table2 as order by col3. when selecting from table2 it looks like data is not correct at all. most of the fields contains nulls and other fields contain different values.

Comment: You should apply the same `order by` when selecting table2 if you want ordered result

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56679664/2700344 ?

Comment: inserted data in table 2 itself is wrong, so order by on table 2 also gives wrong result.